# A group of thirty people is selected at random. What is the probability that at least

Tags: probability

1-A group of thirty people is selected at random. What is the probability that at least two of them will have the same birthday?

My answer is
$$\frac{_{365}P_{30}}{365^{30}}.$$
When I calculate this I got error in my calculator.

2-How many people would you have to have in a group so that there is a probability of at least $0.5$ that at least two of them will have the same birthday?

My answer is
$$\frac{_{365}P_n}{365^n} = 0.5$$
What next? How can I get the value of $n$?

Comment: what is (365)P_{30} / 365^(30)?

Comment: What is the probability that all have different dates for their birthday? And what is the complement of that event?

Comment: permutations  -->   365P30/365^30

Comment: In 1) the probability that all have a different birthday-dates is calculated. This is the complement of the event that at least $2$ have the same birthday date. So you are close but not correct. If $p$ denotes your answer then the correct answer is $1-p$.

Comment: it remembers me a Gamow puzzle :)

Answer (score 1):

There are $366$ possible birthdays so for all $30$ of them to mismatch, each one needs a different birthday.  However not all birthdays are equally likely but assuming they are, the probability for part $1$ of your question is $1$ - [($365/366$) * ($364/366$)... * ($337/366$)] = about $70.5$%.

For there to be at least a $50$% chance of at least $2$ people having the same birthday, you would need $23$ random people.

Try using www.WolframAlpha.com and typing in the following (to solve part $1$ of your question):

1 - product of x/366 for x=337 to 365

To solve part $2$ of your problem type this into www.WolframAlpha.com:

1 - product of x/366 for x=344 to 365

Comment: Why not assume $365$ equally-likely days? After all, surely $P({\rm Feb\ }29)$ is closer to $0$ than to $P({\rm Feb\ }28).$ But other than that, this is the "standard" answer to the question. I wish whoever downvoted it had explained why.

Comment: Yeah I got downvoted on a correct answer that doesn't seem fair.  I even gave the reference to WA so the person can play around with the numbers.  Whether you use $365$ or $366$ days in a year, the answers are very close so it is somewhat arbitrary.  I wanted to emphasize that there are really $366$ possible birthdays, not $365$.

Comment: Also, I doubt that all $365$ birthdays are equally likely because of certain things like weather which affects hormones but that is beyond the scope of this site.  People are not fair coins is what I am trying to say so I would say there is no exact answer to this question, just an approximation.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the $365$ birthdays other than February 29 are _not_ equally likely in real life. But most people (myself included) don't want to attempt a "realistic" version of the problem. I usually prefer $N=365$ (for reasons given) but it's also interesting to know what the results are for$N=366.$ Especially for the "$50$%" question, I think you could make a good argument for using $N=366$ to get a "conservative" estimate.